# What kind of cheese is 눈꽃치즈 (snow cheese)?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

눈꽃치즈 is typically translated into English as "snow cheese" on Korean menus (and sometimes "Hangulized" as 스노치즈). In most food pictures it just appears to be a very finely shredded, light-colored cheese. My best guess is that it's mozzarella, parmesan, or a whitish variety of cheddar, but it's hard to tell just by looking at it. This leaves me wondering if 눈꽃치즈 is even a particular kind of cheese at all, or if it's a catch-all expression for very finely shredded/powdered cheese sprinkled over a dish.

So, my question: **Is 눈꽃치즈 a particular kind of cheese, and if so, what kind of cheese is it?**

Comment: Googling for '눈꽃치**스**' brings up 'Did you mean 눈꽃치**즈**?'. Or maybe it could be either?

Comment: Ahh! You are absolutely right! I'll edit the spelling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a proper noun, a brand name of a specific fried chicken restaurant franchise. 
By the way, I think it can't be called as a kind of cheese, because it is just a cheese-flavored seasoning powder. It is a combination of a little bit of cheese(usually, Grana Padano cheese), corn starch, fat, and some seasonings that synthesized artificially.